# Use of "purdah" metaphorically: appropriateness

Tags: word-usage, metaphors, appropriate

When I was a kid, the word "purdah" was regularly used in the UK metaphorically to mean a (usually voluntary) screening or separation. For example, the chancellor had a period of pre-budget purdah.

Given its original context, is this still considered appropriate in professional contexts in the UK?

Comment: ***Purdah*** is the pre-election period in the United Kingdom, specifically the time between an announced election and the final election results. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purdah_(pre-election_period). ***Purdah***: A state of seclusion or secrecy:
the supermarket’s own self-imposed purdah on the GM issue. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/purdah

Comment: Huh, I've never heard of *purdah*, though I knew of the practice (though it is more widespread than the Islamic world: the Jews do it, as well as some more obscure or historical sects of Christianity. I'm thinking particularly of the *[Cagot](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cagot)* who had to use a separate entrance and seating section in church).

Comment: It is certainly still in common usage for any period of separation.

Comment: @Chenmunka In BrE, it seems like it. As a native speaker of AmE, I have never encountered the word before.

Comment: @DanBron - for what it is worth: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=purdah%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cpurdah%3Aeng_gb_201&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpurdah%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpurdah%3Aeng_gb_201%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Josh61 Thanks for the link, I had not know about the `:dialect` syntax to restrict a search to a particular dialect. That's going to be useful!

Comment: @DanBron As a native speaker of BrE, I have never encountered the word before either.

Comment: @RoaringFish - It appears to be used mainly in Britain: "Purdah" in British English: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/purdah

Comment: @Josh61~ that is what everybody is saying, but I was born, educated, and spent the bulk of my adult life in Britain and I have never seen or heard this word being used. This makes it very hard for me to believe that it is in widespread use in Britain.

Comment: For example here http://www.thetimes.co.uk/tto/news/politics/article2565071.ece is a newspaper article from just a few years ago which uses the term without scarequotes.

Comment: I don't know where you would like to use the term, but I think it is perfectly fine. It is  probably not so common as some users suggest.

Comment: @DanBron Purdah is a social practice of some Islamic and Hindu societies.  It is the segregation of women from public life, and in extreme forms from all public sight.  Jews do not practice purdah.  Orthodox sects separate men and women during worship, and by custom, women do not touch men they're not related to (e.g., they don't shake hands). But this is hardly purdah.

Comment: The term is pretty much unknown in the US, and, to the extent it is known, carries the connotation of an eastern religion.  It's definitely not applied to elections, except perhaps in some pejorative sense.

Comment: Oddly, after years in abeyance, political purdah has made a bit of a comeback since I wrote this: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-36516509

Answer (score 1):

I've heard it before; it was meant to convey secrecy and did not actually refer to any cultural practice.

The British empire with its colonies spread over the South Asian/South East Asian subcontinent encouraged the import of quite a few Persian/Indian loan words into Brit English and these were once pretty widespread in popular usage. 'Have a dekko', 'good ol' Blighty', bungalow, dhow, dinghy, verandah, mufti, dacoit, chitty, juggernaut, pukka, pundit along with the more familiar curry, vindaloo, balti, cashmere, pyjama, chutney, typhoon, thug, karma :) .

We seem to have purged some of the more exotic ones out of our regular vocabulary. Not many people would recognize some old loan-words in their original context any more, especially this one. Worse yet, it would be very easy to misinterpret the usage and the sentence would end up giving out unintentional negative vibes. It really wouldn't be considered too appropriate in a professional setting imho but it depends on where you're planning to use the term.